# How to print/upload (a web-page) directly into my Google Drive account?

Tags: macos, printing, google-docs

Is it possible to, from the OS X 10.6 print dialog, print the web-page directly into my Google Documents account?  I can save as PDF and upload it, but, well, I want to cut out the middleman (ie, me; I make too many mistakes...).

I tend to use Chrome to browse the web in case that's relevant.

Are there Google Docs upload-helpers in general?  I tried `gdocuploaded` (an Adobe AIR App) but it refused to so much as launch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Update – March 25, 2012:** The old workflow stopped working due to changes in the Google APIs. This one should fix it. Follow step 1 below, then [download the new version](https://github.com/slhck/Print-to-Google-Docs/tree/master/workflows) of the workflow.

---

You can create a so called *Printing Workflow*. It will be available in the options you have when printing a PDF. We need some steps for this, so bear with me:

### 1. Install gdata-python

Go to the [gdata-python download page](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list) and download the latest version. Unpack the archive, and navigate to the folder in Terminal. Then enter:

```
python setup.py install
```

You're done.

### 2. Install Google Command line tools

First, install `pip`.

```
easy_install pip
```

Then, install the [Google Command Line tools](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl) over it.

```
pip install googlecl
```

Now, GoogleCL [has a bug](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/issues/detail?id=463) occurring when uploading to Google Docs. We need to manually fix the following file (replace `2.6` with the actual version you have):

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/googlecl-0.9.13-py2.6.egg/googlecl/docs/client.py
```

With the contents from this file from the GoogleCL repo (click the "raw" link):

> http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/source/browse/trunk/src/googlecl/docs/client.py?r=589

### 3. Authorize GoogleCL

The Google Command line tools allow you to access Google services over the command line. To do that, you have to first authorize your computer to access Google.

Enter the following

```
google docs list
```

It will prompt you for your username first. After you've entered it, you'll get to your Google account page. Click "Grant Access" and then copy the bold verification code that looks something like `x9rS2qPNUb` from the website.

Paste it into the Terminal again and hit enter. Now GoogleCL is authorized and will list all your Google Docs. Neat.

### 3. Get the upload script

We can use these tools to upload files to your Docs without ever needing to open an application. If you want to skip the next part, [download the workflow](https://github.com/slhck/Print-to-Google-Docs/tree/master/workflows) from step 4.

If not, [download the shell script here](https://github.com/slhck/Print-to-Google-Docs/blob/master/scripts/upload.sh). Copy the contents of this script, we'll need it later.

### 4. Create a print plugin

We're almost there. If you want to skip the following, [download the workflow](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/84665/download/gdocs.zip) from my Dropbox account.   If that ever goes offline, see [my github repo for it](https://github.com/slhck/Print-to-Google-Docs). Unzip and copy the `workflow` file to `/Users/username/Library/PDF Services`. You're done.

Otherwise, if you want to do it yourself, do the following:

- Open *Applications/Automator.app*.
- Select "Print Plugin".
- From the left, search for "Get Selected Finder Items" and drag that to the right pane.
- Now, search for "Run Shell Script" and drag that to the right too.
- In the header of "Run Shell Script", change the "Shell" to "/bin/sh" and the "Pass Input" option to "As arguments"
- Now paste the contents of the shell script into the box below.

Once you're done, your workflow should look like this:

[image]

Go to *File → Save As* and enter a name, for example "Upload to Google Docs".

### 5. Test the plugin

The workflow is now available in the PDF menu when you print anything. From anywhere. You can now "print" to Google Docs from your Mac.

[image]

In fact, it will also open the file you just uploaded to view it in your browser. If you want to disable that and "silently" upload, remove (or uncomment with `#`) the lines in the script that say `open $URL`.

Comment: Beautiful example for a print plugin that's not *just* "Save as PDF to Yet Another Document Management Application".

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an easier way if you use Chrome. You can print directly to Google Drive from within Chrome:

1. Select print from the menu
2. Select "Print with Google Could Print" as a destination printer
3. Click "Print" in the print dialog
4. The main print dialog closes, and the Could Print dialog comes up. "Save to Google Drive" will be the first option. Select "Print" and it will create a print job and close the dialog when done.
5. The PDF will appear in your root folder of Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Check [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/drive?_category=extensions) as there are few extensions which can achieve that such as:

- [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) by Google Drive team

  > Save web content or screen capture directly to Google Drive.
- [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/pacllhnfaalmndlofaggllkjdonlgjnc) by pdfzorro.com

  > Save PDF, images or webpages - opened in Chrome - to your Google Drive.
- [Save Images to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-images-to-google-dri/bbnbpfcfjajhfopdpdmcpkmalgoigjco)

  > Allow to Save images from web page to Google Drive
  >
  > The Save to Google Drive Chrome extension helps you save web content or browser screenshots to your Google Drive. The directory location and format of saved HTML pages can be controlled with the extension's options page.